# How to get the SQL Server name and the other arguments of odbcConnect function in RODBC package?

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

I want to connect to SQL Server using R and am trying my hand at RODBC package.
In the odbcConnect function, i confused about the arguments:-

1. For the Server, i went to regedit and odbc and saw SQL Server Native Client 10.0
2. For database, i wrote Tableau (which is the name)
3. For uid and pwd i gave my credentials

Following is the code that i wrote:-

```
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=.;database=Tableau;trusted_connection=yes;uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!")
```

But i got error in the code:-

```
   Warning messages:
  1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=.;database=Tableau;trusted_connection=yes;uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!") :  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 2, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. 

2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=.;database=Tableau;trusted_connection=yes;uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!") :[RODBC] ERROR: state HYT00, code 0, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired

3: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=.;database=Tableau;trusted_connection=yes;uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!") :[RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 2, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

4: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=.;database=Tableau;trusted_connection=yes;uid=SQL_User;pwd=""""!") :

ODBC connection failed
```

Can anyone recommend any solution? I don't understand the errors too well

Comment: how do you normally connect to the database? do you have sql server management studio? if so, you can find the server name there

Comment: I connect to the SQL Server Management Studio by using the Remote Desktop Connection. How can i get the version of the server?

Comment: you don't need the version of the server.  If you are connecting with Remote Desktop Connection, the server name is probably the name of the machine you are remoting into. The IP Address should work as well.

Comment: In case it's an issue, if you did `regedit` on the SQL Server machine, it may be different than your local system. You can use `RODBC::odbcDataSources()` to make sure you are using the right `Driver` string. (This doesn't help with the server address, just thought I'd pipe in.)

Comment: actually its done ! i got a solution cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;Database=Tableau;uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!")